# how to calculate the output voltage of specific circuit using superposition law

Tags: thevenin, wheatstone-bridge

[image]

Hi, How to calculate the output voltage of the circuit is shown below. Using the superposition principle is the best or the one that you recommend. I'm using strain gauges based on the Wheatstone bridge, which brings me here. I calculated Thevenin resistive load and voltage source(302ohm, 0.7v). If I had Wheatstone bridge resistor values R1, R2, R3, R4, 350ohm, 350, 350, and 200, what is the voltage across a voltmeter?

Comment: Smells like you have generated a new XY-case (=think  that solving problem Y solves the original problem X and ask only for Y) That's OK if solving Y really solves X, but as well one can make some error which makes solving Y actually useless. Often XY case questions contain some obscurities which reveal that the case is an XY case. Your obscurity is the existence of Wheatstone in the question and a schematic which can be whatever else. I guess you'll get something actually useful only by revealing the original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Using the superposition principle is the best or **the one that you
> recommend**.*

[Millman's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millman%27s_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20electrical%20engineering%2C%20Millman%27s%20theorem,Millman%2C%20who%20proved%20the%20theorem.) seems the most appropriate: -

[image]

Image [from here](https://electricalvoice.com/millmans-theorem-limitations-applications/).