# Circuit analysis - Finding the voltage

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, resistors, voltage-divider

[image]

How to analyze the above circuit to find the voltage at the node A?

Like, can someone tell like, which resistors can be taken as series and which are parallel to find the voltage at node A?

The actual value of voltage at node A from simulation is 2.87V.

But, I was thinking like, the 820k and 220k in the 12V branch form a voltage divider and hence at node A, there will be 2.53V. Then, the 220k from 3.3V branch and the 220k in the 12V branch form a voltage divider and hence 1.5V. So, adding the two, 2.53V + 1.5V = 4.03V.

But this is incorrect.

Can someone tell me how to arrive this with simple intuitive approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *How to analyze the above circuit to find the voltage at the node A?*

[Millman's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millman%27s_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20electrical%20engineering%2C%20Millman%27s%20theorem,Millman%2C%20who%20proved%20the%20theorem.): -

[image]

Note that one of the sources above will be 0 volts in your circuit.

Image from [here](https://electricalvoice.com/millmans-theorem-limitations-applications/) and [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/616182/how-to-calculate-the-output-voltage-of-specific-circuit-using-superposition-law/616183#616183) (if you have ad-blocking).

> *Can someone tell me how to arrive this with simple intuitive approach?*

Millman's theorem is basically a short-cut method that avoids converting each voltage source (and associated series resistor) into a current source and associated parallel resistor. With current sources in parallel the total current is easy to calculate and, with three parallel resistors combined, this easily yields the voltage at node A in your circuit. Millman's just short-cuts the details.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!

Comment: You already knew how to answer your own question, but had a hangup on series and parallel combining. None of the resistors is in series or parallel with another resistor.  Parallel means connected at both ends and series means connected at one end with nothing else connected there. The current through the 3.3 volt source is (3.3-VA)/220k, through the 12 volt source (12-VA)/820k and through R3 is (VA/220K) and it's equal to the sum of the other two. You probably haven't heard superposition mentioned yet in your course and you may never hear of Millman's Theorem again.

Comment: @stetch please modify your comment to include the `@person` thing.

Answer (score 1):

Use superposition theorem. Find the node voltage because of each source and algebraically add them. None of these resistors are series or parallel.